# Are there any benefits to using the http package vs. built in HttpRequest class?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart, dart-html

I'm writing a web application using Dart and Polymer, and we decided to use the http package, specifically the BrowserClient class, to talk to our web API.  Upon building the application, I am greeted with a warning message the following warning message:

WARNING: dart:mirrors support in dart2js is experimental,
         and not recommended.
         This implementation of mirrors is incomplete,
         and often greatly increases the size of the generated
         JavaScript code.

Now our application does not do anything with reflection/mirrors directly, but I can tell from the warning message that something in the http package is importing mirrors and using it.  I know it's considered bad practice to use mirrors for anything related to code running in the browser because it may bloat the compiled JavaScript. I guess my question is, why should we use this over the HttpRequest class built into the core libraries if there is a risk of it bloating the compiled output?

Answer (score 0):

`dart:mirrors` is hard to configure so that it doesn't cause code bloat for browser applications (so it doesn't hurt tree-shaking), therefore it is discouraged and you get this warning from `dart2js`

The http package uses `dart:mirrors` for a trick that allows it to share some code between browser **and** console applications that imports 'dart:io` which is normally prevented.

This trick doesn't cause any code bloat and you are **safe to use** it. 
The Dart team is working on a better solution (configurable imports) so this trick isn't necessary anymore but it is not yet fully available.

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense.  I felt the interface for the BrowserClient was a lot nicer to use since the methods were based on HTTP verbs, so I think we will stick with the http package for now.  Thanks.